# Problem/issues with Yarn (yarn.js) version upgrade

Tags: node.js, hadoop-yarn, child-process

When trying to upgrade the yarn version form “0.28.4”  to “1.22.19” with to buffer an output in the given scenario , but it’s not working with updated version.
Any suggestion/solution ?

[image: Need to run this command (child_process.execSync)]

Working fine with yarn version form “0.28.4”
[image: Working fine with yarn version form “0.28.4”]

Problem with  yarn version form “1.22.19 ”  ?

[image: Problem with yarn version form “1.22.19 ”]

trying to upgrade the yarn version form “0.28.4”  to “1.22.19” and facing problem with yarn library.

Answer (score 0):

This has been fixed now.

When we execute node command using "child_process.execSync" it return buffer , so we have to convert it into string before parse and keep it in new varibale.

In the above problem,  it was reassign to same variable.